# c++ , issues with return type of member functions in subclasses

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Before I ask my question, I'll describe the scenario.

Let's say I have a class called `BinaryOperator` with 2 subclasses: `And`, `Or`.

I am wondering if it is possible for me to define a function `f()` in `And` with return type `Or*` like so:

```
Or* And::f()
```

And also define a function `g()` in `Or` with return type `And*` like so:

```
And* Or::g()
```

When I try to do this, I end up with a compile error saying along the lines of " 'Or' does not name a type".

Please, if you can, any clarity will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE].

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, why not just post some representative code?

Comment: Hi sorry, the reason I didn't post any code is because most of the code isn't my own and I don't know if it would be ok for me to post it. Also, my question isn't about the specific code but rather in general if given two subclasses can i define a member function in each class with return type of a pointer to the other class

Comment: @AsgarHussain "*the reason I didn't post any code is because most of the code isn't my own and I don't know if it would be ok for me to post it*" - then write your own [mcve] that represents the same problem the real code is experiencing. "*if given two subclasses can i define a member function in each class with return type of a pointer to the other class*" - of course you can, you just need to use **forward declarations** to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
class Or; // <-- forward declaration

class And : public BinaryOperator
{
public:
    Or* f();
};

class Or : public BinaryOperator
{
public:
    And* g();
};
```